# Find or Query Mongodb Data with logical conditions AND

Tags: mongodb

My Mongo data like this

```
{
    "_id" : "5a5ffef0869422169c7aa01b",
    "email" : "example@gmail.com", 
    "checkin" : "2018-2-28 5:12",
    "checkout" : "2018-2-28 6:12",
}
```

I have 2 arrays:

1. `checkin : ['2018-2-28 5:12','2018-2-28 5:13','2018-2-28 5:14']`
2. `checkout : ['2018-2-28 6:12','2018-2-28 6:13','2018-2-28 6:14']`

And my query to find `email`.

```
db.getCollection('test').find({checkin : {$in: checkin}}, {"email": 1, "_id": 0})
```

I got result

```
example@gmail.com test@gmail.com
```

Now, I got a problem. I want to find `email` got `checkin` AND `checkout`.
It's mean only find `email` have value in `checkin - checkin array` AND `checkout - checkout array`

I tried this query but not ok

```
db.getCollection('test').find({checkin : {$in: checkin}},{checkout : {$in: checkout}}, {"email": 1, "_id": 0})
```

Comment: Try `db.getCollection('test').find({checkin : {$in: checkin},checkout : {$in: checkout}}, {"email": 1, "_id": 0})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.getCollection('test').find(
 { $and: [
          {'checkin' : {$exists: true}},
          {'checkout' : {$exists: true}} 
        ] 
},
{
  'email':1
//just set email:1 to get only email in projection
})
```

This qyery returns email if 'checkin' AND 'checkout' both arrays exist.
Just in case you want to check size of array you can use

```
'checkin':{ $size:{ $gt:1 } }
```